# neural network,matlab programming

Tags: matlab, neural-network

what can i do to solve this error in my program(learning the net)? it appear after sim. the net.

```
Error in ==> network.sim>simargs at 236
switch class(P)

??? Output argument "Pi" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2008b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\@network\sim.m>simargs".

Error in ==> network.sim at 173
  case 2, [err,X,Xi,Ai,T,Q,TS,matrixForm] = simargs(net,X);

Error in ==> mlptrptest at 62
y = sim(net,A{1,1})
```

Comment: Yes, of all the errors I've seen recently not having "Pi" assigned really takes the cake ...

Comment: What does your own code look like? How did you install the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* Don't fall into the same trap I did. There is also a function called [SIM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/sim.html) in [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink/) that will likely show up in searches for the function [SIM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/sim.html) in the [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neuralnet/)...

The first thing I would check is that the second input argument `A{1,1}` is of the correct form. Specifically, `A{1,1}` would have to be a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) or a matrix of [doubles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html#f2-101310). If it is of any other form, like a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html) or a matrix of [any](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-12135.html) [other](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-97022.html) [class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-47856.html), you will get the error you are seeing. Admittedly, this particular error isn't handled very well by the subfunction `simargs`, in that it gives you some cryptic messages that don't really tell you the basic problem, which is that your input is not in the right format.

Here are a couple things to check:

- Do you really mean to pass the *first element* of cell array `A` as an input argument, or do you mean to simply pass the cell array itself? If it's the second option, just do this:

  ```
  y = sim(net,A);
  ```
- If you *do* mean to pass the first element of `A` as an input argument, double-check it's class using the function [CLASS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/class.html):

  ```
  class(A{1,1})
  ```

  If you don't see `double` displayed, it means the first element of `A` is not the right type. If it is a matrix, you can [convert it to double](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/double.html) before you pass it to [SIM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/sim.html) like so:

  ```
  y = sim(net,double(A{1,1}));
  ```

Comment: I agree. Whenever it is a Matlab built-in function that throws an error, it is a good idea to make sure it's being used properly.

Comment: @mohammad: I updated my answer. Hope this one is a little more helpful. ;)